# Select - if loop

Tags: loops, macros, spss

How do I create a loop that gives several other dataframes through a variable

e.g

```
TEMPORARY.
SELECT IF (VAR   EQ "4206").
SAVE TRANSLATE OUTFILE ="4206_GR.XLS"/TYPE =XLS
/VERSION=8  /REPLACE /FIELDNAMES.
```

Where VAR is one variable of my database and 4206 is string value of the VAR.

My variable may have several other values.

How I do one loop for this?

Comment: This can be done using macro commands. Look at the DEFINE - ENDDEFINE commands in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with a macro:

```
define !dolist (vls=!cmdend)
!do !i !in(!vls)
TEMPORARY.
SELECT IF (VAR EQ !quote(!i)).
SAVE TRANSLATE OUTFILE =!concat ('"',!i,'_GR.XLS"')
/TYPE =XLS/VERSION=8/REPLACE/FIELDNAMES.
!enddefine.

* now run the macro for all the values you need.
!dolist 4206 2202 8592 1234 4321.
```